# SQL SELECT JOIN and save origin table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I want to SELECT JOIN two tables but when I loop through the results I want to be able to identify the table from which each row has been returned.

Something like:

```
SELECT table1.ID, table_origin = { TABLE ORIGIN } FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
```

A row should look like `['ID' => 0, [table_origin] => 'table1' ]` or `['ID' => 10, [table_origin] => 'table2' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliases:

```
SELECT t1.ID AS t1_ID,
       t1.col1 AS t1_col1,
       ...
       t2.ID AS t2_ID,
       ...
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON ...
```

Alternatively when you don't need to join:

```
SELECT *, 'table1' AS table_origin
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'table2' AS table_origin
FROM table2
```